# Run a shortcut (.lnk) from Task Scheduler

Tags: powershell, windows-task-scheduler

I'm attempting to create a Task Scheduler task that runs a .lnk shortcut, which starts a PowerShell script using `pwsh.exe` with arguments. When I set the lnk as the program to run when task is triggered, `pwsh` window opens with normal prompt.

From more testing, it seems Task Scheduler does not run the .lnk itself and it runs the target directly, while ignoring all arguments and options (e.g. setting the program to start with minimized window also does nothing).

Is there a way to force task scheduler to correctly run the .lnk, without bypassing it and ignoring arguments?

Steps to replicate:

1. create .lnk with Target set to `pwsh -command "pause"` (or any other program that behaves differently when arguments are passed)
2. Create Task Scheduler task that attempts to run the .lnk file.
3. Manually trigger the task.
4. Normal PowerShell instance opens instead, ignoring the argument `-command "pause"`

Comment: Uhhhh!!!??? Why!!!??? This is really not a thing as you discovered, and this is Windows proper, nothing PowerShell can do to change that. Just put the code in the task. If you are going to use a file, then use a proper .ps1 file.

Comment: @postanote The rest of the system respects PATHEXT and lets me run .lnk files without issue - only Task Scheduler ignores them.

Comment: Do you run your script with the proper permissions? Do you set a "minimized window argument" in the link properties? A PS script is not a regular program, it's meant to open an interface, then run whatever commands you want it to, then either close the command line window or wait for user input, or for some other program or script to deliver the action and/or information your commands implied.

Comment: You are mistaken about `%PATHEXT%`. It is merely a list of extensions to try when looking for a command. It is only for convenience and does not change any fundamental behavior. // Links can only be “executed” by the shell. Task Scheduler does not use the shell.

Answer (score 1):

How to run a shortcut / link (.lnk) in Windows Task Scheduler

Program/script: cmd

Add arguments (optional): /c "%userprofile%\Downloads\4.ps1(F).lnk"

[image: How to run a shortcut (.lnk) in Windows Task Scheduler]

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce the OP's original problem scenario exactly. For me, after running the task, a "*How do you want to open this file?*" dialogue appears. I assumed that for step 2, the `Program/script` field script is set to `<path-to-lnk-file>`.

Anyway, there are two workarounds that I have found, in addition to the `cmd.exe /c <path-to-lnk-file>` workaround provided by user *somebadhat*.

1. For your task:

- set the `Program/script` field to `%WinDir%\explorer.exe`
- set the `Add arguments (optional)` field  to `<quoted-path-to-lnk-file>`.

This method has one noteworthy disadvantage that I have come across:- if you have set the `.lnk` file `Run:` field to `Minimized` or `Maximized` in the shortcut's properties sheet, it will not be respected when the `.lnk` file is opened.

2. Alternatively, you can use a wrapper script to run your shortcut:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
objShell.ShellExecute WScript.Arguments(0), "", "", "open", 1
```

Save the code to `runshortcut.vbs`.

For your task:

- set the `Program/script` field to `%WinDir%\System32\wscript.exe`
- set the `Add arguments (optional)` field  to `<quoted-path-to-runshortcut.vbs> <quoted-path-to-lnk-file>`.

AFAIK, this method has no downsides. However, it's worth mentioning that [VBScript is deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/whats-new/deprecated-features-resources#vbscript) and will likely be removed in future versions of Windows.